# How do I pass a querystring parameter to a link in an article?

Tags: joomla, joomla-article

We have some banner ads linking to an article in Joomla and they are passing a reference code in the URL, like this:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=378&Itemid=249&ReferenceCode=WB6074
```

Inside the article, we're linking to a signup form on another web site and we need to pass the reference code in that URL's querystring.

How do I do this?

Is there a way to embed PHP in an article?  If so, then I could just use `$_GET["ReferenceCode"]` to stick that parameter in the URL.

Answer (score -1):

There are numerous modules that allow you to load PHP or Javascript in a module. There are also plugins which would do the job within an article. Have a look on the extensions.joomla.org site